# Php Code to put same random number to other part

Tags: php

i want to create a php random number between 1 to 1000000  and what that same random number at 4 different part of site. i tried but i am getting random number at all different place. but i want the same number at all place. if any one can help me please?

I am using this

```
<?php
function url() {
  $rand = rand(1, 1000000);
  return $rand;
}
?>
```

and when I echo using this so numbers are random at all place

```
<?php echo url(); ?>
```

Comment: i am using this  <?php
function url() {
$rand = rand(1, 1000000);
return $rand;
}
?>   and when i echo using this so numbers are random at all place <?php echo url(); ?>

Comment: don't put code in comments, make sure your question proper has all the information needed. I edited it for you, but please do so yourself next time. (Also, the `I` in English is _always_ written in uppercase, and sentences start with a capital letter.)

Comment: `and when I echo using this so numbers are random at all place` what'd you expect? rand is for producing random numbers, you know

Comment: @ Col Shrapnel i want same random number at all place (not random number at every place)

Comment: @ Col  so is there not any way so i can get same value at 4 diffrent place.. RAND is creating one time but then i want that value same value at 4 different place (which will not be called random. u can say copy paste)

Answer (score 2):

Store the random number in a variable, otherwise you're calling the random function every time, which will result in different numbers.

```
$randomNumber = rand(0, 1000000);
echo $randomNumber;
```

You can use `$randomNumber` in all the locations of your script and it will stay the same as long as the page isn't refreshed.

**EDIT:**
Just saw your comment. The code snippet you're using is a random function wrapped inside a function and works virtually the same as calling `rand(0, 1000000)`. Every time the url function is called, the random function is run and you'll get different results.

Comment: This is the complete code, I'm afraid. :) But if you want to use the random number across pages and page refreshes you're better off using the answer given by Coulton.

Comment: @ Mensch u mean i use this   <?php
$randomNumber = rand(0, 1000000);

}
?>   and for echo i use this <?php echo $randomNumber; ?>

Comment: Yup, but it won't work across pages or refreshes, in that case a new number is generated.

Comment: i want same random number at every place unique for every visitor

Comment: i tried this but it gave this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/public_html/

Comment: I'm not sure what "every place" means. But if you want to store a random number for the whole browser session of a user (or even longer), you'll have to use something like sessions or a database, as Coulton has pointed out.
The extra } in your code is likely the result of something else. Probably the residue of another function you've previously deleted. Find the line number the error refers to and see if an extraneous } is present.

Comment: every place mean at 4 diffrent area of same page.

Comment: No need for a session in that case, unless you want the number to be the same after a page refresh.

Comment: no i have no issue if number change on page refresh.. i just only need same number at 4 place . i dont mind these number change on page refresh but numbers should be same

Comment: Done u are perfect MENSCH .. some guys were confusing me in cookie and session things lolz  Love u

Comment: Glad to be of help. Though I would advise you to more fully acquaint   yourself with the basics of programming (variables, statements, functions, etc.) It will help you to understand the concepts discussed here by others, but also allows you to make the necessary technical connections to make a lot of code posted here as an answer work. There are some very good online resources, but also books starting from beginner level to very advanced (like this line of books: http://www.apress.com/9781430224730).

Comment: thank you.. my repu is low dtz why i cant rate your answer.. sorry :(

Comment: also do you have this book free link? which you shown me ?  PHP for Absolute Beginners

By Jason Lengstorf

Comment: Linking to copyrighted material is prohibited here, I think. Could you mark my answer as the correct one, please, if you think it helped you enough? A higher answer acceptance percentage will net you more answers in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the random number in a session variable, accessible to the same user:

```
function url() {
  $rand = rand(1, 1000000);
  return $rand;
}

session_start();

$_SESSION['random_number'] = url();
```

Then on any page access the random number on each page on your site using:

```
// Make the session variables available 
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['random_number'];
```

Comment: Down vote?  Apart from storing the data in a database, a session variable is the next logical thing....

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel He wants the same number `at 4 different part of site`... read question AND the manual.  That's the whole point in a SESSION to store server side data for a user.  What has the SESSION LIFETIME got to do with anything?  He can destroy the session or variable whenever he wants.

Comment: simply i want 2 php code .. one php code create a random number and another php code with get that number as it is. not another random

Comment: @james this will do just that.  Run the first snippet of code, and this will store the random number that your function produces.  Then create another file with the second code snippet, and you will see that the same number appears again.  You could repeat this for as many pages as you want.

Comment: i added this <?php
function url() {
  $rand = rand(1, 1000000);
  return $rand;
}
start_session();
$_SESSION['random_number'] = url();
?>   but getting error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/

Comment: Please try: <?php function url() { $rand = rand(1, 1000000); return $rand; } session_start(); $_SESSION['random_number'] = url(); ?>  If you're getting this message it means that you're closing a '}' when the matching '{' doesn't exist